# Why am I reaching my connection limit and timing out queries when I use Heroku-Redis for multithreading?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, heroku, redis

I'm hosting a Django web app on Heroku, and it uses Redis to run a task in the background (this gets kicked off by the user when they submit a form). The task often has to make multiple queries to an API using pexpect, sequentially. When I had it all set up locally, I had no problems with timeouts, but now I regularly run into two problems: TIMEOUT in the pexpect function and "max client connections reached".

I'm using the free tier of Heroku-Redis, so my connection limit is 20. This should be more than enough for what I'm doing, but I notice on the Redis dashboard that when I run the program, the connections stay open for a while afterwards (which is what I suspect is causing the "max connections" error -- the old connections didn't close). I used heroku-redis on the command line to set it so idle connections should close after 15 seconds, but it doesn't seem like they are. I also should only have 4 concurrent connections at the same time (setting in Django settings.py), but I regularly have 15 or so spawned for a single run.

How do I actually limit the number of redis connections generated for my program and make sure they actually close when they finish their job? And how do I prevent TIMEOUTs (which I suspect happen because no connection is available to finish the query)? I don't understand why so many Redis connections are necessary for a single background task.

This is the relevant content in my Django settings.py file. I use celery to run my background task, so I don't directly interface with Redis.

```py
CACHES = {
    "default": {
         "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
         "LOCATION": "redis:// censored",
         "OPTIONS": {
            'CONNECTION_POOL_CLASS': 'redis.BlockingConnectionPool',
            'CONNECTION_POOL_CLASS_KWARGS': {
                'max_connections': 4, 
                'timeout': 15,
                'retry_on_timeout': True
            },
        },
    }
}

# the line below lets it run locally
# BROKER_URL and CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://guest:guest@rabbit:5672/%2F'

# I'm not sure what the difference between BROKER_* and REDIS_* are,
# so I've included them both for good measure 
BROKER_BACKEND = "redis"
BROKER_HOST = "amazonaws.com censored"  
BROKER_PORT = 20789
BROKER_PASSWORD = "censored"
BROKER_VHOST = "0"
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 4 # limit # of celery workers

REDIS_URL = "redis://censored
REDIS_HOST = "amazonaws.com censored" 
REDIS_PORT = 20789
REDIS_PASSWORD = "censored"
REDIS_DB = 0
REDIS_CONNECT_RETRY = True

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = REDIS_URL
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_REDIS_MAX_CONNECTIONS = 4
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 30

DATABASE_URL = "postgres:// censored"
# I added this for Heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

This is where I initialize Celery. I use a @shared_task(bind=True) decorator for my background task function.

```py
app = Celery('aircraftToAirQuality', backend=settings.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND, broker=settings.REDIS_URL)
app.conf.broker_pool_limit = 0
app.conf.broker_transport_options = {"visibility_timeout": 60}
```

My UI regularly checks to see the progress of the task to update a progress bar. This is just a simple HTTP Post call.

And this is the pexpect code, in case that's relevant. Since I'm sending sensitive content (passwords and stuff), I've removed much of the text.

```py
def use_pexpect(self, query):
    cmd = 'censored'
    pex = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
    pex.timeout = 30
    index = pex.expect(censored)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pex.sendline(censored)
    pex.sendline(query)
    pex.expect(censored)
    result = pex.before
    pex.sendline('quit;')
    pex.close()
    return result
```

Right now, I can infrequently run my task successfully. The longer the task is supposed to run for (make 10 queries instead of just 3), the more likely it is that the program will fail before it finishes running. My background task should be able to make queries sequentially and my UI thread should be able to check its progress without any connection limit or TIMEOUT problems.